# Is it possible to create retro type shaders?

Tags: materials, shaders

I'm trying to re-make the old street fighter 2 box art. I'm still in the sculpting phase right now, but I'm just wondering if the water color style is even possible as a shader?  I know there are some advanced toon shading techniques, but old retro water paint art, I haven't seen any.  So anyone know if it's even possible?  If not, I'll just got for the generic cell shading everyone is famous for.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are at least half a dozen tutorials on youtube on how to create a water color toon shader in Blender.  Scan through them and pick one that suits your style.

Comment: I don't think the images attached are necessarily water shader style...  They're "drawn".  I don't know what technique was used I assume it's water color.  I've never seen a shader that looks like these.  That's why I ask if this style is even possible?